# python subprocess.Popen hide real "display name"

Tags: python, popen

I want to execute a subprocess in python, and the subprocess require an argument to specify a password. By default, everyone who can login this machine can get the password with the `ps` utility when my subprocess is running.

And I know Popen has an `__executable__` param, which can hide the real program name, but cannot hide the password argument of the subprocess.

How can I hide my password?

PS: I running on linux.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: also what is the subprocess command: Is it something you can control how it handles its arguments or is it an existing command you have no control over?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that *for* subprocess, but there is a library to do it *from* subprocess: http://code.google.com/p/py-setproctitle/

The method is specific to each OS; some systems don't support that at all. If possible, give password to the subprocess by other means (e.g. via stdin pipe).

Comment: Wouldn't that still leave a window where the password is exposed (between the parent creating the subprocess and the subprocess hiding its arguments)?

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess` doesn't expose an API to do that.  I'd recommend passing the password to the command using an environment variable:

```
subprocess.check_call('command --password="$PASSWORD"', shell=True,
                      env=dict(os.environ, PASSWORD=password))
```

Comment: It won't achieve the goal — the shell's process will have password masked, but the real command started by the shell will have it exposed just the same.